# Changing bounds of summation after differentiating symbolic sums

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion

Suppose, I have a function written as Taylor-Maclaurin series

```
f = Sum[c[n]*x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

Now, I wish to differentiate this expression with respect to `x` symbolically

```
D[f, x]
(* --->
Sum[n*x^(-1 + n)*c[n], {n, 0, Infinity}] *)
```

Resulting expression is correct except from the fact that expansion starts from `n=1` now, because `n=0` term vanishes after differentiation (if done explicitly).

In this case it isn't a problem because `n=0` term vanishes anyway, but for more complicated computations it may be the reason for breaking further simplifications.

So, my question is:

How can I teach Mathematica to correctly change bounds of summation?